# soapenv:Server.userExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog for Hotelbed WSDL api

Tags: php, soap, curl, wsdl, soap-client

I got response 500 internal server error when i run below code, I think code is perfect, so can anyone help me about this?

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
$xml .= '<CountryListRQ echoToken="DummyEchoToken" xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages CountryListRQ.xsd">';
$xml .= '<Language>ENG</Language>';
$xml .= '<Credentials>';
$xml .= '<User>username</User>';
$xml .= '<Password>password</Password>';
$xml .= '</Credentials>';
$xml .= '</CountryListRQ>';

$url = 'http://212.170.239.71/appservices/ws/FrontendService?wsdl';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8; action="getCountryList"'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $xml));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$result = @curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
exit;
if($result === false) {
    echo "Error performing request";
} else {
    $xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($result);
    echo 'status is ', $xml_doc->status, '<br/>';
    if ($xml_doc->status == 'SUCCESS') {
        print_r($result);
    } else {
        echo 'Error is ', $xml_doc->errormessage, '<br/>';
    }
}?>
```

I got response like this,

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sat, 02 Feb 2013 06:02:12 GMT
Server: Resin/2.1.17
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

soapenv:Server.userExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.we3mpf01
```

Can anyone help me? How can i get country list using this hotelbed api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below http service url :

```
http://212.170.239.71/appservices/http/AcceptanceTest
```

I thing on the time hotelbeds server was down, that's why this error happen.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you are missing the SOAP wrapper elements, i.e. <soap:Envelope>, <soap:Body>, etc -- see the basic usage example:

http://www.soapuser.com/basics3.html

However instead of interacting with the server using curl, which is a low level HTTP tool, I recommend checking out the SOAP package:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

This will do all of the wrapping for you and give you a nice OO layer to work with.

If you are deliberately learning the lower level details of SOAP for some reason, then at least the XML you have in your example needs to be inside the <soap:Envelope> and <soap:Body>, not just out on its own.